# Redirect website login to different IDP

Tags: iptables, internal-dns, hosts, shibboleth

My organization has a Shibboleth/IDP service set up. Now that I am getting involved, I am first setting up my own basic IDP on a test server to learn the ropes. In order to test functionality, I want to be able go to one of our production sites and -- if accessing it from my workstation in the office -- have the login be redirected to my IDP instead of the main production IDP. I think I should be able to do this locally without affecting anyone else by editing IP routing rules on my machine in `/etc/hosts/` or `iptables`, but I'm not sure how and I'm pretty new.

Basically, I'm wanting to add a condition locally on my machine such that if I try to access `https://productionsite.domain/secure/login`, my local routing rules redirects me to my own IDP. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply do the following step:

1. Get the URL where the IDP is listening for requests (you should find it in the metadata.xml of the IDP, more exactly in the field "Location" of element "SingleSignOnService"). The url is of the type: "schema://hostIDP/percorso".
2. add an entry to your "hosts file" with the following couple: 127.0.0.1 hostIDP
3. Setup your system to listening to the port 80 and setup the same "Location" field of the element "SingleSignOnService".

Remember that:

1. It works iff the binding used is Asynchronous, ie. with the Browser.
2. The response will be signed with your personal certificate, therefore the ServiceProvider will discard it.